# Svg not visible in device but visible in android xml

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, svg, android-imageview

[image]

I have used SVG's for these icons, the icons are visible in xml but not visible in device . 
following is my code :

```
                ` <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:weightSum="10"
                   >

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="25dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1.5"
                        app:srcCompat="@drawable/email_id_icon"
                        />

                    <EditText
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:id="@+id/et_email"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="8"
                        android:textColor="#fff"
                        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                        android:hint="Email Id"
                        android:textColorHint="#fff"
                        android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                        />

                </LinearLayout>`
```

I have gone through similar questions on SO, most of them suggested to use 
          `android: src` instead of `app:srcCompat` , but I have to use srcCompat only because of SVGs. So what should I do?

**Edit -** 
I have done the same thing in another activity's layout . 
here is the working code :

```
  <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/login_form_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/textView2"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="20dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="10">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/username_iv"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="25dp"


                android:layout_weight="2"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/email_id_icon" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:id="@+id/username_et"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="8"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:hint="Email Id"
                android:textColorHint="#fff"
                android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                />

        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:background="#fff" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="10">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/password_iv"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="25dp"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/password_icon" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/password_et"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="8"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:hint="Password"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:fontFamily="roboto"
                android:textColorHint="#fff"
                 />

        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:background="#fff" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/btn_login"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/login_button_style"
            android:text="Login"
            android:textSize="@dimen/headingText"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="#fff" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/tv_forgetpassword"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:text="Forget your password ?"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="@dimen/headingText" />


    </LinearLayout>
```

I did not want to have icons in 4 resolutions so I made a single .png image and converted into .svg using Android Studio's Vector asset .

Comment: Likely to do with your layout_width being 0dp (perhaps try "wrap_content" instead of "0dp"). Have you tested different emulated devices to see if it's a problem specific to your device?

Comment: width:"0dp" is for weights. 
I have done similar thing in another activity , everything is same there and it is working fine , but I don't know what is the problem here.

Comment: You shoud be able to use SVG's with android:src attribute. Have you tried that?. I can't see a mistake on your code so far.. any error or warning trace  ?

Comment: I didn't notice the weight set, my bad. Could you post the working code? I was thinking maybe you were missing `vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true` in your default gradle build, but if the same code is working elsewhere that must be set.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you are using `AppCompatActivity` and not `Activity`. If you are using `Activity`, then write in your activity / fragment:

```
imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_svg_image);
```

Also add in `build.gradle`:

```
android {  
    defaultConfig {  
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true  
    }  
}
```

And for 4.x versions of Android you can also add a support for `TextView`s' inner drawables. This is also actual for `ImageView`s.

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        // This flag should be set to true to enable VectorDrawable support for API < 21.
        AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

Then in AndroidManifest add this file:

```
<application
    android:name=".MyApplication"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    ...
</application>
```

Sometimes it crushes on some old devices. Then wrap your drawable inside:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_svg_image/>
</selector>
```

and set it instead of SVG:

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/drawable"
    />
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Add vectorDrawables in build.gradle (app)

   `defaultConfig {   vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true   }`
2. Then use `androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView` instead of ImageView.
3. Make sure to use `android:src` to specify the svg added with Vector Asset tool.
4. Done!

Answer (score 1):

you can use [VectorDrawable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/VectorDrawable.html)

Here is a [tool](http://inloop.github.io/svg2android/) to convert you svg to `VectorDrawable`

On pre lollipop device svg support is not quite comprehensive.

Add this in your `build.gradle`

```
 android {  
    defaultConfig {  
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true  
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Late answer but hope it helps someone. If someone is using constraint layout as the parent, with `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` and if any of the inner views have `android:layout_height="match_parent"`, then the inner view is not visible. Making the height of the inner elements to wrap content and constraining it to the top and bottom of the parent constraint layout element made it work for me.