# "Drawable not found" crashing issue in Android 4 version

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout

In Firebase Crashlytics, I get the following error on Android version 4 phones.
The file ic_arrow_back_black_24dp.xml exists in drawable folders. Please help.
https://prnt.sc/sauoit
Existing folders are available in the picture.

Thanks

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.defaultmailproject.myproject/com.defaultmailproject.myproject.ui.activities.MainActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable-hdpi-v4/ic_arrow_back_black_24dp.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f0800c9

Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.defaultmailproject.myproject/com.defaultmailproject.myproject.ui.activities.MainActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable-xxhdpi-v4/ic_arrow_back_black_24dp.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f0800c9

Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.defaultmailproject.myproject/com.defaultmailproject.myproject.ui.activities.MainActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable-v19/ic_arrow_back_black_24dp.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f0800c9
```

MainActivity Toolbar ic_arrow_back_black_24.dp.xml;

```
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    final Drawable upArrow = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_arrow_back_black_24dp);
    upArrow.setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.white), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
```

Comment: pleaser read developers page before dealing with drawable https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource

Comment: have you tried to clear the caches by restarting Android Studio?

Comment: @ShoaibK.  The application is live on Google Play. Users are encountering this error.

Comment: If you use SVG, have images rendered before on Android 4? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43594751/svg-not-visible-in-device-but-visible-in-android-xml/52551226 fro SVG compatibility on Android 4. If you didn't face the exception before, see what libraries or gradle you had updated.

Comment: @CoolMind Sorry. This doesn't work. The ic_arrow_back_black_24dp.xml file is the back key for the action bar.

Comment: Why do you put SVG in several folders? It should be in one folder `drawable`.

Comment: Also I think, `final Drawable upArrow = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_arrow_back_black_24dp);` is a problem line. Maybe images shouldn't be loaded from vectors this way.

Comment: @CoolMind I get the same error only when it's in the drawable folder.I also placed it in other folders to resolve the error. But I still could not get a solution. Sorry for my terrible english.

Answer (score 1):

make sure that file
ic_arrow_back_black_24.dp.xml

is in drawable folder not in drawable-v24

just cut it from drawable-v24 and paste it in drawable